# Find a string in a 2D array and then go to corresponding column

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I'm converting a CSV into an Array. The CSV has the first column which consists of titles the describe what is in that column. In my case: product ID | product name | product cost | quantity

I'm trying to go through the array, find the string `item1` and then go to that item's quantity, which in the same line, but in a different column.

For example:

**product ID | product name | product cost | quantity**

-----001----- | -----item1----- | -----5.99----- | -----3-----

-----002----- | -----item2----- | -----2.99----- | -----5-----

So I want to go this array, find the string `item1` in line index 1, then go to column index 3 to extract the quantity into a variable. Then I want to store into a variable to ultimately print out `there are only 3 item1's left` or something of the sort.

This is what I got so far:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test2 {

    public static List<List<String>> csvToArray() {
        String fileName = "c:\\temp\\test.csv";
        File file = new File(fileName);

        // this gives you a 2-dimensional array of strings
        List<List<String>> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner inputStream;

        try {
            inputStream = new Scanner(file);

            while (inputStream.hasNext()) {
                String line = inputStream.next();
                String[] values = line.split(",");
                // this adds the currently parsed line to the 2-dimensional string array
                lines.add(Arrays.asList(values));
            }

            inputStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return lines;
    }

    public static void printArray(List<List<String>> lines){
        int lineNo = 1;
        for (List<String> line : lines) {
            int columnNo = 1;
            for (String value : line) {
                System.out.println("Line " + lineNo + " Column " + columnNo + ": " + value);
                columnNo++;
            }
            lineNo++;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        csvToArray();
        printArray(csvToArray());
    }
}
```

As you can see, in the method `printArray` I'm just printing out the Array to get a reference of where I am, but once I try to add `if`'s then Im getting lost.

Any help would be great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Determine the indexes of the clumns of interest and iterate through the lines, printing and feeding a variable for future use along the way.
Creating a class to represent a csv line seems to be over-engineering here but depends on the requirements, of course.

Code is ***not tested***.

```
/*
   Preprocessing:
   Determine column indexes of product name and quantity.
   Use the informstion available.

   Simple case: column indices are known beforehand.

   This code scans the csv header lines for given strings.
*/
final String s_HEADER_PRODUCT   = "product name";
final String s_HEADER_QUANTITY  = "quantity";

HashMap<String, int> quantities = new HashMap<String, int>();

int idxProduct   = -1;
int idxQuantity  = -1;

List<String> headers = lines[0];
int columnNo = 0;
for ( columnNo = 0; columnNo < headers.size(); columnNo++ ) {
    if ((idxProduct < 0)  && headers[columnNo].equals( s_HEADER_PRODUCT )) { idxProduct = columnNo; }
    if ((idxQuantity < 0) && headers[columnNo].equals( s_HEADER_QUANTITY )) { idxQuantity = columnNo; }
    if ((idxProduct >= 0) && (idxQuantity >= 0)) {
        break;
    }
}

/*
   Print out.
   After the loop, 'quantities' will hold a map of product names onto quantities.

   Assumptions:
      - Quantities are integer values.
      - Product names are unique within the file.
 */
lineNo = 0; 
for (List<String> line : lines) {
    if (lineNo > 0) { // skip header line 
        System.out.println("Item '" + line.get(idxProduct) + "': " + line.get(idxQuantity) + " specimens left.");
        quantities.put ( line.get(idxProduct), Integer.parseInt ( line.get(idxQuantity) );
    }
    lineNo++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to map each line to a "Product" object.
This news class will contains attributes like productID, productName, productCost & quantity.

Once each lines map to a product object, you just have to find the product with the productName you want, then you can access its other properties easily.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you use `List<String[]>` instead of `List<List<String>>`.
But for your problem, you can do something like that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
    System.out.println("There are only " + lines.get(i).get(3).replace("-", "") + " " + lines.get(i).get(1).replace("-", "") + "'s left");
```